# How to remove duplicated documents in MongoDB 4.0

Tags: mongodb

Lets say I have the next documents in the colecction `sample`:

```
{_id: 1, comp_index1: "one", comp_index2: "AAA", field: "lots of text" }
{_id: 2, comp_index1: "two", comp_index2: "BBB", field: "mucho texto" }
{_id: 3, comp_index1: "one", comp_index2: "CCC", field: "more text" }
{_id: 4, comp_index1: "two", comp_index2: "AAA", field: "más texto" }
{_id: 5, comp_index1: "one", comp_index2: "AAA", field: "lots of text" }
```

I want to make `comp_index1` and `comp_index2` an actual unique compound index.

If I run `db.sample.createIndex( { comp_index1: 1, comp_index2: 1}, { unique: true } )` it will throw `E11000 duplicate key error collection` so I decided to remove duplicates first (due the removal of *dropDups* option).

Right now I have this brute force algorithm that does the job:

```
db.sample.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                comp_index1: "$comp_index1",
                comp_index2: "$comp_index2"
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } }
    }
], { allowDiskUse: true }).forEach(function (doc) {
    for (i = 1; i < doc.count; i++) {
        db.sample.remove({
            comp_index1: doc._id.comp_index1,
            comp_index2: doc._id.comp_index2
        },
        {
            justOne: true
        });
    }
    print("Removed " + (i-1) + " dups of <" + doc._id.comp_index1 + " " + doc._id.comp_index2 + ">")
})
```

The problem is that I have over 1.4 M documents and there are almost 200 000 dups, so this takes forever to be done, so I was wondering if there is a faster better approach.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours I finally managed to come with a 1000 times faster solution.

```
var ids = [];
db.sample.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                comp_index1: "$comp_index1",
                comp_index2: "$comp_index2"
            },
            unique_ids: { $addToSet: "$_id" }
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } }
    }
], { allowDiskUse: true }).forEach(function (doc) {
    var i = 0;
    doc.unique_ids.forEach(function (id) {
        if (i++ > 0) ids.push(id);
    })
})
db.sample.remove({"_id": {$in: ids}});
```

Despite being overall the same approach, saving in RAM all the ids to remove and then performing `remove` with the operator `$in` is way way faster. This one was took only few seconds to execute.

If you come up with another solution that does not requires using RAM, please share.

Answer (score 0):

I recently create a code to delete duplicated documents from MongoDB, this should work:

```
const query = [
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        comp_index1: "$comp_index1",
        comp_index2: "$comp_index2"
      },
      dups: {
        $addToSet: "$_id",
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: {
      $gt: 1,
      },
    },
  },
];

const cursor = collection.aggregate(query).cursor({ batchSize: 10 }).exec();

cursor.eachAsync((doc, i) => {
  doc.dups.shift(); // First element skipped for deleting
  doc.dups.map(async (dupId) => {
    await collection.findByIdAndDelete({ _id: dupId });
  });
});
```